# Need help identifying python data structure accessed by 'data[x,y]'

Tags: python, arrays, stock

I'm attempting to implement a sample function for stock analysis I found online [1].

```
def normalizer(Data, lookback, onwhat, where):
    for i in range(len(Data)):
       try:
          Data[i, where] = (Data[i, onwhat] - min(Data[i - lookback + 1:i + 1, onwhat])) / 
          (max(Data[i - lookback + 1:i + 1, onwhat]) - min(Data[i - lookback + 1:i + 1,onwhat]))
       except ValueError:
            pass
       Data[:, where] = Data[:, where] * 100
    return Data
```

How is the `Data` variable being referenced?
The `Data` is time-series OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) for some number of days for a given stock.

- I think it should be a list of lists but referencing a list of lists with `data[x,y]` is 
  invalid. (I think). My only experience with a list of lists would require using notation 
  like `data[x][y]`.
  This leads me to think the `data` var is NOT  a list-of-lists.
- Does anyone recognize this style of notation for a 2-dimensional array?

I'm using Python 3.7.

[1]: credit to Sofien Kaabar

Comment: Look at `numpy`

Comment: Have you tried ```print(type(Data))```

Comment: link to the source would help. Also, you can always print `type(Data)` and see what you get.

Comment: Data is probably a [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) array.

Answer (score 0):

This is older but here's a working example. Original commenters are correct that is in a numpy array. I used pandas to get the array, it is a list of lists with OHLC data, but also requires an empty column to put the result in.

Article that sources the original author: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-indicator-to-be-added-to-your-trading-system-ac65e70bbdd

Pandas data:

```
          open   high    low  close newcolumn
Date
2002-05-23  16.19  17.40  16.04  16.75
2002-05-24  17.00  17.15  16.76  16.94
2002-05-28  16.99  17.25  16.20  16.20
2002-05-29  16.30  16.30  15.20  15.45
2002-05-30  15.51  15.51  15.00  15.00
...           ...    ...    ...    ...       ...
2002-10-08   5.75   5.99   5.47   5.67
2002-10-09   5.74   5.75   4.86   5.22
2002-10-10   5.29   7.35   4.85   7.09
2002-10-11   7.12   7.40   6.25   6.59
2002-10-14   6.50   7.49   6.49   7.48
```

Numpy array (not the full array - list of lists):

```
array([[16.19, 17.4, 16.04, 16.75, ''],
       [17.0, 17.15, 16.76, 16.94, ''],
       [16.99, 17.25, 16.2, 16.2, ''],
       [16.3, 16.3, 15.2, 15.45, ''],
       [15.51, 15.51, 15.0, 15.0, ''],
       [15.1, 15.1, 15.0, 15.07, ''],
       [15.12, 16.09, 15.07, 15.8, ''],
       [15.9, 15.96, 15.55, 15.65, ''],
       [15.55, 16.23, 15.5, 16.06, ''],
```

function arguments are index positions
3 - close column
4 - write to newcolumn
50 - lookback

```
normalizer(df.values, 50, 3, 4)
```

once you get to the 50th position, you'll see the newcolumn calculations kick in

```
   [13.3, 13.44, 12.29, 12.48, ''],
   [12.41, 12.43, 9.89, 10.89, 0.0],
   [10.9, 11.38, 10.65, 10.85, 0.0],
   [11.14, 11.25, 10.4, 10.65, 0.0],
   [10.65, 11.11, 10.4, 11.11, 6.371191135734058],
   [11.15, 11.25, 10.51, 11.15, 6.925207756232686],
   [11.18, 11.5, 10.9, 11.02, 5.124653739612177],
   [11.24, 11.3, 10.55, 10.6, 0.0],
   [10.75, 11.27, 10.56, 10.82, 3.0261348005502144],
```